# How do I stop parallel imgs from being pushed aside when using CSS3 to transform?

Tags: css

I currently have an issue where I have three separate images and I am using CSS3 to transform them upon hover.

I have tried to put them in divs, a table and to just have the plain images. Have tried to float them all in one direction or having #1 left #3 right #2 none. Have tried to use z-index to overlay also with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CSS:

```
#contentrecent {
  float: right;
  width: 380px;
  height: 400px;
}

#contentrecent img {
  float: left; 
  width: 120px;
  height: 350px;
  background-image:url(images/snapshot1.jpg);
  overflow:hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#contentrecent img:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  width:600px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-400px,-100px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-400px,-100px);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="contentrecent">
  <h1> Recent </h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="120" height="300" align="left"><img src="images/snapshot1.jpg" /></td>
      <td width="120" height="300" align="left"><img src="images/snapshot2.jpg" /></td>
      <td width="120" height="300" align="left"><img src="images/snapshot3.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>                 
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue. I put this code into a jsFiddle and the transforms seem to be working as expected.

Comment: Don't use tables for layouts. Use a styled unordered list.

Comment: The transform works fine but if you look at the jsFiddle the images on the right of the one transformed decide they want to zoom off to the east.

Answer (score 0):

Make a clone of the image, position it absolute over the original and apply the transform to the copy.